# Htaccess redirection for url ending with dot(.)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website and there is a booking page , `booking.php` .  I want to redirect people who is typing **dot(.)** at the end of url to correct url .

For example some one type `example.com/booking.php.` then I have to redirect to `example.com/booking.php`  How can I do this?

I tried and it is not working

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/appointment.php. http://www.example.com/appointment.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`RedirectMatch`** for that.

Check this code :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /appointment\.php\.$ /appointment.php
```

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

---

**OR**

You can use **`mod_rewrite`** to redirect it.

Check below code :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php\.$ $1.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Reference : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule